# Where can I download source for MySQL Connector/J

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Googling didn't help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Funny because copy-pasting "MySQL Connector/J" into Google got me the source code as the first result.

But if you're looking for source code for a free application, the most convenient way I've found is to look up the related package in Ubuntu (or Debian) and download the related source code.

It works best if you're using them, you can simply use aptitude search / apt-get source combo to download it. But if you're using another operating system, you can simply do a Google search like `site:packages.ubuntu.com mysql connector/j`

Comment: My first result is http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/ . It offers me a download link, which leads to a package with the source code and binaries.

Comment: Sure enough, if you actually download it (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/), the source is in the archive. I would have made that assumption with a more fully-open project, but I didn't assume it in this case. Nice one.

Comment: Wow, my bad -- I knew about this page but didn't expect they bundle source with the main download. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

The source code for MySQL Connector/J can be found on GitHub:

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j