# How to see all SQL statements sent by mysql-connector-java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, slf4j

I'm trying to use `Slf4JLogger` from [mysql-connector-java 5.1.20](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j.html), but can't see anything in log. I added `logger=Slf4JLogger` to JDBC URL and configured SLF4J to LOG4j bridge. All other classes' log messages are visible. What is the secret?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/bfg/mysql-connector-java-log) sheds some light. You could start by not specifying anything, and look whether the standard log file is created. Possibly use FLUSH_LOGS command.

Comment: This library is my last resort.. I still hope that mysql-connector-java can log to SLF4J. Unfortunately, sources are not open :(

Comment: Have you set `profileSQL=true`? What does your log4j configuration look like?

Comment: I got Slf4JLogger to work with slf4j + log4j when setting `profileSQL=true` as Qerub said.  Also, the source is available publicly as noted in another SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245660/where-can-i-download-source-for-mysql-connector-j).

Comment: It works for me with `logger=com.mysql.jdbc.log.Slf4JLogger` and  mysql-connector-java 5.1.39